# Convergence of the following dirichlet series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to establish the behavior of the following series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}}{n^x}$$ where $x$ is a real number.
Clearly for $x < 0$ the series diverges, while for $x > 1$ it converges, since it is absolutely convergent. Also I know that this is a Dirichlet series and has an abscissa of convergence. It has to be greater than $0.5$ by [Convergence of series with negative terms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748948/convergence-of-series-with-negative-terms). Is it possible to find it in a closed form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The abscissa of convergence is $c$ the least real number such that $\sum_{n\le N}(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor}=O(N^r)$ for all $r > c$.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_series#Abscissa_of_convergence)

It is $c=1/2$ because $$\sum_{n< N^2}(-1)^{\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor} = \sum_{m=1}^{N-1} (-1)^m (2m-1)$$

Comment: Can you elaborate more the last part?

Comment: Sure I made a stupid mistake, confusing $N$ and $N^2$.

Comment: Ok thank you! Cheers